# Unable to run Junit5 test cases with Maven 3.8.6

Tags: java, maven, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

Test class location: `module > src > test > java > TestRunner.java`

And to debug I have written both testng test and junit 5 test. But only, testng test is executing.

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestRunner
```

I had checked other posts and they suggested to use surefire 2.22.0 and specify the jupiter engine as a dependency inside the plugin, but this did not help.

Moreover, `mvn dependency:tree` did not list out JUnit4 dependency.

Any suggestions please?

Below is my plugin currently:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Why you want to run testng and junit5 test cases togather? Use only one. Add junit5 separate test dependency instead of plugin dependency.

Comment: Only define the dependency to junit-jupiter-engine but not explicitly as a plugin dependency...and use most recent version of surefire/failsafepluing (3.0.0)...

Comment: I added testng just to debug to find junit test is not running. Moving jupiter engine dependency out of plugin is not working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Tests are now running after using recent versions:

1. `maven-surefire-plugin` - `3.0.0`
2. `junit-jupiter-engine` - `5.9.1`